# Rails/Bootstrap JS related functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've been troubleshooting this issue for a while but it appears as if no Bootstrap JS functions are working for example the navbar-collapse icon bar or a Carousel slider. (Even tried copy pasting the official Carousel slider code with no alteration and it won't work). The icon bar won't open and the slider won't change slides. Any input is appreciated.

Using Rails 4.2.6
Twitter Bootstrap

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= twitter/bootstrap
```

application.html.erb (icon bar)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>PADECO Prototype</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%= yield %>


        <nav id="top-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a id="brand" class="navbar-brand" href="#">PADECO</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="telephone">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>Contáctanos al: <b>(81)8345-32-42</b>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>




        <nav id="bottom-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul id="center-nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Quienes Somos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </body>
</html>
```

home.html.erb (slider)

```
<div class="container-fluid home-container h-container-attributes">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="..." alt="first">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="..." alt="second">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="..." alt="third">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any console.errors?

Comment: try replacing `//= twitter/bootstrap` with `//= require bootstrap` and make sure to put bootstrap right after you require jquery.

Comment: @Madalin No console errors, everything seems fine, that's why it's so hard to pinpoint the problem

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using is the proper markup for that version?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and using therubyracer as JS interpreter